# How does Modulus work with negative integers?

Tags: java, math, modulus

I am running a for loop and inside my loop I have the following:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 12; i = i + 2){
        System.out.println("i = " + i);
        System.out.print("3 - i % 3 (i is at " + i + ") = " + (3 - i % 3));
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("3 - i (" + (i) + ") = " + (3 - i));
    }
```

I do understand how Modulus works normally or with positive numbers, but I do not understand how it works with negative integers?
Can anyone explain it to me please?

Many thanks.

Comment: [Is this a math question?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic)

Comment: What is there with this question which JLS doesn't tell you?

Comment: Well, actually I guess it is?
But I am asking this question as it relates to Java in my code.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, no, because this is programming language dependent. For example, `-10 % 6` is different in Java vs Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 4 %  3 ==  1
-4 %  3 == -1
 4 % -3 ==  1
-4 % -3 == -1
```

Changing the sign of the first number changes the sign of the result. The sign of the second number doesn't matter.

This is true in many languages (C, C++, Java, Javascript) but not all languages (Python, Ruby).

Comment: Thats great. Thank you Paul

Comment: @PrimalScientist - If "that's great", you should accept this answer. It's the Stack Overflow way.

Comment: I am. I need to wait 8 minuets. :)

Answer (score 2):

`a mod b` is very well defined for positive integers `a` and `b`. What if `a` or `b` are negative? There are three choices that are consistent with that base definition:

1. `a mod b` is always positive.
2. `a mod b` has the same sign as `a`.
3. `a mod b` has the same sign as `b`.

Different languages will choose one of these three choices. There is no singular correct answer.